# Extending multiple classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I know Java doesn't support multiple inheritance by not allowing to extend more than one class. I just want to know if there is a workaround for my issue.

I've a class named `CustomAction` which needs to extend two abstract classes, `BaseAction` and `QuoteBaseAction`. I can't change any of these abstract classes and make one extend other.

These abstract classes have method implementations which I need to make use of. I can't create an interface also since an interface can extend only another interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the Composition pattern might help you - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Do those classes implements any interface? Could you show to us those classes?

Comment: These abstarct classes implements some other classes. I need to make use of method implementation in these abstract classes.

Comment: Then the Inner class solution provided below is the right one for you as it will have access to methods of both the abstract classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
public class CustomAction extends BaseAction {
  class Inner extends QuoteBaseAction {

  }
}
```

Comment: It's not an inheritance: you cannot substitute QuoteBaseAction with CustomAction. It'll only work, if the only goal is to reuse existing code. But in this case, there's no need to extend from BaseAction, it can be reused via composition mechanism.

Comment: CustomAction needs to extend two abstract classes (requirement) and that's what the above code does. You create an instance of Inner class and you have all the methods / functionalities of both the classes.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Once again, inheritance is absolutely not about code reusage. You cannot pass CustomAction instance to a method which accepts QuoteBaseAction.

Answer (score 5):

[**Composition**](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html) is the way to go.Make one of your abstract class as part of your class.

```
public abstract class Abs1 {
 //
 } 
public abstract class Abs2 {
 //
 } 
public  class Main extends Abs1 {
 Abs2 abs2 = ...
//impl
 }
```

Comment: I didnt understand the last part.  "Abs2 abs2 = ...".  Abs2 cant be instatiated using new operator. How can I make use of a method implemented in Abs2 using the object abs2?

Comment: @jijo you could use an anonymous class which implemnts those methods in ABs2. like Abs2 abs2 = new Abs2(){ //implemnts all those abstract methods in abs2 }

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot inherit from two abstract classes.
You can work around it if abstract classes implement interfaces. In this case, you can replace inheritance with composition:

```
abstract class BaseAction implements Action { ... }

abstract class QuoteBaseAction implements QuoteAction { ... }

class CustomAction implements Action, QuoteAction {

   private BaseAction baseAction;
   private QuoteBaseAction quoteBaseAction;

   public Bar methodFromAction() {
       return baseAction.methodFromAction();
   }

   public Foo methodFromQuoteAction() {
       return quoteBaseAction.methodFromQuoteAction();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet there would be delegation. You could implement both interfaces (if these classes use an interface) or create interfaces to use there and then hold an instance of each class inside your class to which you delegate your calls.

Answer (score -1):

In java it's possible for abstract classes to extends other abstract classes.